# "Cannot find all types required by the 'async' modifier" when building for Windows Store

Tags: parse-platform, unity-game-engine, windows-store-apps

After building the game for a Windows Store app, I got 5 errors

[image]

I am using the Parse.com service in my game.

What may cause these errors and how do I resolve them?

Comment: Please include your code. Not just a screenshot of it.

Comment: there are too many codes , some in unity and some in visual studio
whatever , the errors in this code "MainPage.xaml.cs"
here is the code : http://pastebin.com/g5BCPjRn